# How to make react rechart chart responsive?

Tags: reactjs, responsive, recharts

I couldn't make a bar chart responsive. I used react recharts for making this chart. I used ResponsiveContainer, but it didn't worked.
My code:

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
    <BarChart width={400} height={600} data={data}>
      <Bar dataKey="delivered" fill="#80dead" />
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" fontSize="8px" />
      <YAxis dataKey="delivered" />
    </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try remove width and height or pass this props to ResponsiveContainer

Comment: then height is 0 and nothing is visible